# .net 6 asp.net web core api apiversion gives error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi Just addeded ApiVersion to .net 6 asp.net web api and I get this error when I execute a call .What Am I missing?

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
```

and I get

```
"type": "https://httpstatuses.io/500",
"title": "Internal Server Error",
"status": 500,
"detail": "The constraint reference 'apiVersion' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.",
"exceptionDetails": [
    {
        "message": "The constraint reference 'apiVersion' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.",
        "type": "System.InvalidOperationException",
        "raw": "System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'apiVersion' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.
```

I am using

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `builder.Services.AddApiVersioning();` in Program.cs or `Startup.cs`(if you have) file

```
using Steeltoe.Management.Tracing;

namespace core6api
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            //builder.Services.AddHostedService<BackgroundWorkerService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHostedService,BackgroundWorkerService>();
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            //
            // Add this line
            builder.Services.AddApiVersioning();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
            
            var app = builder.Build();
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the AddApiVersioning was missing .Thank you .,. I really thought I had added it.. again thanks